# ¿Cómo consultar columnas en mayúscula con Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Tengo una tabla llamada `Cargos`. De ella quiero consultar todos los registros, pero que vengan en mayúscula y compararlo con uno convertido en mayúscula. En la base de datos tengo varios registros, entre ellos uno que es `Operario`.

Si lo hago de la manera manual, queda de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT nombre FROM cargos WHERE upper(nombre)=upper('opeRarIo')
```

En la base de datos funciona correctamente. Me indica que hay un registro.

Pero no logro hacerlo con Laravel. Esto es lo que intentado:

```
$sql = DB::table('cargos')->where('upper(nombre)', '=', 'upper("'.$req->valor.'")')->get();
```

y este otro:

```
$sql = Cargos::select(array('id'))->where('upper(nombre)', '=', 'upper("'.$req->valor.'")')->get();
```

Ambos me dicen:

> Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  no existe la columna «upper(nombre)»

Comment: No me queda muy claro para qué quieres convertir todo a mayúsculas, ¿sería lo mismo si las convirtieras a minúsculas?

Comment: si es lo mismo, es solo para comprobar que haya un registro igual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo usaría `ilike` de Postgres para este tipo de consultas, con el fin de ignorar si es mayúsculas, minúsculas o mezclados como el ejemplo que das:

```
$sql = Cargos::select('id')->where('nombre', 'ilike', $req->valor)->get();
```

Comment: gracias hermano tambien sirve, no sabia de la existencia del "ilike".

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con:

```
$sql = Cargos::select(array('id'))->whereRaw('upper(nombre)', '=', 'upper("'.$req->valor.'")')->get();
```

En vez de **where** usar **whereRaw**, Saludos.

Comment: ahora no me lanza error, pero no me arroja el resultado esperado. Como si no encontrara el resultado en la BD.

Comment: Te recomiendo instalar debugbar e ir viendo y probando las consultas que te arroja.

Comment: listo ya lo instale, gracias por la recomendacion, no sabia de esa herramienta, me facilitara muchas cosas :D
este es el query que manda laravel "select "id" from "cargos" where upper("opeRarIo") upper(nombre)"

Comment: solucionado gracias :D, era cuestión de sintaxis, acá la final, ----> $sql = DB::table('cargos')->whereRaw("upper(nombre) = upper('".$req->valor."')")->get();

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza whereRaw

Aquí tienes el ejemplo.

`$sql = DB::table("cargos")->whereRaw('upper(nombre) = upper("'.$req->valor.'")')->get();`

Comment: gracias bro :-D